# dynamic fields in redmine based upon input

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I am using custom fields in redmine. I need a set of custom fields to populate based upon how a user answers a question. for instance, if a user chooses "a" they get a series of 3 custom fields that pertain to "a" ..if a user chooses "b" they get a series of custom fields that pertain to "b" is this possible? any help would be great!

Comment: as it stands this does exist in the stock Redmine and I do not know of any plugins that implement it. If you need it you may need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the answer

Answer (score 0):

Are You search ready plugin or want to develop your own with neccesary functionality?

In case of develop You may pass selected field from view to controller as parameter. Then check which field was selected and set value to it from other parameter.

I think that somethng like this:

view

```
<%= form_tag ... do %>
    <%= label_tag :selected_field %>
    <% select_tag :selected_field, options_for_select(['field1', 'field2',...])

    <%= label_tag :value %>
    <% text_box_tag :value, value %>

    <%= submit_tag 'save' %>
<% end %>
```

and controller method

```rb
def update
    obj = SomeClass.find_by...  # get your instance
    case params[:selected_field]
        when 'field1'
            obj.field1 = params[:value]
        when 'field2'
            obj.field2 = params[:value]
    end
    obj.save
end
```